# Use "find" from a specific relative directory

Tags: shell, directory, string

Suppose I'm in the following directory:

```
/A-dir/B-dir/mydir/… some directories …/x-dir
```

I want `find` to search from `mydir`,
but `mydir` is not specifically known in advance;
it is defined by the current working directory, as being the first directory coming after `/A-dir/B-dir/` (this path is explicitly specified) when going "up" from the current working directory. This way, `find` will search `mydir`, but not any other directories in `B-dir` (otherwise, I could just use

```
find /A-dir/B-dir/ -name … …
```

).

Comment: Your question is confusing. Can you make it more clear ?

Comment: So you are asking that you want to search one folder but ignore the other folders? For instance, you want to search `/opt/` but you don't want to search in `/etc/`?

Comment: Does `find /directory -name {filename}` work?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I tried to make the question more clear. Stéphane already posted the desired answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find "${PWD%"${PWD#/A-dir/B-dir/*/}"}" ...
```

(the first directory component in `$PWD` after `/A-dir/B-dir`)

Or:

```
find "${PWD%"${PWD#/*/*/*/}"}" ...
```

(the first 3 directory components)

Or:

```
find "${PWD%"${PWD#/*/B-dir/*/}"}" ...
```

(the fist directory component after the left-most occurrence of a `B-dir` component in `$PWD`).

With `zsh`, you can also do:

```
find ${(M)PWD#/*/B-dir/*/}
```

Comment: The first line does EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be what you're looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash
last="${PWD/*\/}"
while test / != "$PWD"
do
    cd ..
    this="${PWD/*\/}"
    if test 'B-dir' = "$this"
    then
        find "$last" ...
        break
    fi
    last="$this"
done
```

It assumes you're starting in `/A-dir/B-dir/mydir/... some directories .../x-dir` and works its way up the tree until it reaches `B-dir`. At this point it runs the `find mydir...` command for whatever value of `mydir` preceded `B-dir`.

The current directory (`PWD`) is updated while the script is running. It wouldn't be very hard to avoid the directory change by manipulating a directory path string rather than the implicit use of `$PWD`, but I chose to implement it this way.